# how to rotate spinner of a particular video from list of videos coming from api in angular

Tags: angular

I am getting a list of videos having play and stop icons. I want that the particular video plays after a delay of 5 seconds. Whithin this delay a spinner rotates.  But in my case when i click play icon spinner of all videos get started.

*here is my component.html*

```
        <table class="table table-striped tabs">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>S. No.</th>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr
          *ngFor="
            let data of video ;
            let x = index
          "
        >
          <td>{{ x + 1 }}</td>
          <td>{{ data.Id }}</td>
          <td>{{ data.Name }}</td>
          <td>
            <a>

              <i
                [ngClass]="[
                  loadIcon ? 'fa fa-play pr' : 'fa fa-spinner fa-spin pr'
                ]"
                aria-hidden="true"
                (click)="startCameraByForm(data.Id, temp)"
              >

              </i>


            </a>
            <a
              ><i
                class="fa fa-stop pr"
                (click)="stopCamera(data.Id)"
                aria-hidden="true"
              ></i
            ></a>



          </td>

        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
```

*here is my component.ts file*

```
       startCameraByForm(cameraId: number, temp: TemplateRef<any>) {
     this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(temp);

      this.camIdField = cameraId;
     this.disableCameraIdField();
      }

       onSubmit(camInfo): void {
// product= this.profileForm.value;
this.isSubmitted = true;
if (this.camInfoForm.valid) {
  this.hideModalBox();
  this.loadIcon = false;
  this.camServ.dummyService(this.camInfoForm).subscribe((res: any)=>{
    console.log(res);
    console.log("hello");
    this.loadIcon = true;

  })    
  }   
  }
```

i want that when i click play icon of particular video spinner of that video starts rotating.

[In my case all spinner starts rotating when a particular play icon is clicked as shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYV55.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the value of `loadIcon` in your component. This property is being accessed in all your rows. So they will all share the same state.

Instead you want to check a property scoped in the `data`. Maybe assign `data.isLoading` and check for that. But those details are all up to you and may depend on the wider system you are working in.

Below is a basic example

**component.html**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor='let details of video' [class.isLoading]='details.isLoading' (click)='loadVideo(details)' >{{details.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  video = [{
    name: 'Video1',
    isLoading: false
  }, {
    name: 'Video2',
    isLoading: false
  }];

  public loadVideo( details ): void {
    details.isLoading = (details.isLoading)?false:true;
  }
}
```

**component.css**

```
li.isLoading{
  background: lightblue;
}
```

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zmjgcs

Comment: I assume the line `loadIcon ? 'fa fa-play pr' : 'fa fa-spinner fa-spin pr'` adds a class that sets the spinner. Is that not the case?

Comment: yes loadIcon add a class to set spinner. But i want to make this class active for only selected row

Comment: I inserted a very basic example how to conditionally add classes.